# nix-build alonzo mainnet

Tags: nix, script, mainnet, alonzo

I've installed cardano-node via nix-build:

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node
cd cardano-node
git checkout tags/1.29.0 -b 1_29_0
nix-build -A scripts.mainnet.node -o mainnet-node-local
nix-build -A cardano-cli -o cardano-cli-mainnet
```

But somehow I end up in the Byron era:

```
$CARDANO_CLI query tip --mainnet
{
    "epoch": 10,
    "hash": "237925228211660d367c77f6af0b50542ace82985339c55a48fed0ff201a1217",
    "slot": 222403,
    "block": 222371,
    "era": "Byron",
    "syncProgress": "3.55"
}
```

which script is the correct one for nix-build for alonzo mainnet past HFC event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing.

`"syncProgress"` refers to the percentage of the chain you've synced. Once you get to around 70% it will say "Shelley" and only the most recent epoch will say "Alonzo". This takes a while, unfortunately.